# Не получается реализовать асинхронность

Tags: django, celery

Делаю небольшой веб-сервис на джанге. Суть в том, что клиент со своего аккаунта устанавливает настройки и запускается скрипт. Скрипт выполняется несколько часов, поэтому я использую celery для того, чтобы это выполнялось асинхронно. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой: если запускаю бота с двух аккаунтов одновременно, бот работает только на одном. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: По такому описанию проблемы - помочь трудно. Начнем хотя бы с того, почему решили, что проблема связана с celery?

Comment: Нет нет, проблема как раз, я считаю, не с celery. То есть я понимаю, что задачи попадают в список задач, и выполняется в соответствии с очередью. Просто у меня не хватает знаний, чтобы организовать это правильны образом, и поэтому хотелось бы узнать в какую сторону думать, о чем почитать